# Writing IPV4 sockets server, recv call claims to receive terabytes of data (and dies)

Tags: sockets, ubuntu

Rescucitating code that worked, I put together the following sequence of sockets calls (running on Ubuntu Linux)

The code to initialize the socket calls getaddrinfo, socket, setsockopt, and bind.  It appears to work.

```
    struct addrinfo hints, *servinfo, *p;
    struct sigaction sa;
    int yes = 1;
    int rv;
    port = 8000;
    memset(&hints, 0, sizeof hints);
    hints.ai_family = AF_UNSPEC;  // Make connection IP version agnostic
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM; // Will use Stream sockets and therefore, TCP
    hints.ai_flags = AI_PASSIVE; // use my IP

    char portstr[10];
    sprintf(portstr, "%d", port);
    testResult(getaddrinfo(nullptr, portstr, &hints, &servinfo),
                         __FILE__, __LINE__, Errcode::GETADDRINFO);

    // loop through all the results and bind to the first that succeeds
    for (p = servinfo; p != nullptr; p = p->ai_next) {
        testResult(listenSock = socket(p->ai_family, p->ai_socktype, p->ai_protocol),
                             __FILE__, __LINE__, Errcode::SOCKET);
        testResult(setsockopt(listenSock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &yes, sizeof(int)),
                             __FILE__, __LINE__, Errcode::SETSOCKOPT);
        testResult(bind(listenSock, p->ai_addr, p->ai_addrlen),
                             __FILE__, __LINE__, Errcode::SOCKET_BIND);
        //      close(sock);
        break;
    }

    if (p == nullptr) {
        throw Ex(__FILE__, __LINE__, Errcode::NO_BIND);
    }

    freeaddrinfo(servinfo); // all done with this structure

    //TODO: Make backlog configurable?
    testResult(listen(listenSock, 10), __FILE__, __LINE__, Errcode::LISTEN);

    sa.sa_handler = sigchld_handler; // reap all dead processes
    sigemptyset(&sa.sa_mask);
    sa.sa_flags = SA_RESTART;
    testResult(sigaction(SIGCHLD, &sa, nullptr), __FILE__, __LINE__, Errcode::SIGACTION);
  cerr << "Listening on port " << port << '\n';
}
```

Then the main wait loop:

```
  struct sockaddr_in senderName;
    socklen_t senderNameLen = sizeof(senderName);
    while (true) {
    int senderSock = accept(listenSock, (struct sockaddr *) &senderName,
                                                        &senderNameLen);
    if (senderSock >= 0) {
            cout << "About to receive data: " << (unsigned int*)buffer << "\n";
            while ( (dataSize = recv(listenSock, buffer, size, 0)) > 0) {
                cout << "Received " << dataSize << " bytes.\n";
                req->handle(dataSize);
            }
        }
    }
```

I get in the browser, type localhost:8000 and it triggers the above code.
The accept call works, but receive fails claiming to have received a 64 bit quantity of data which is among other things, larger than the requested buffer size (and larger than all the memory on campus).

Any clues as to what I am doing wrong?

Comment: I think you should be calling `recv` on `senderSock`, not `listenSock`.

Comment: This was the correct answer!  Frame it as an answer and I will mark it correct.